# DiskPart won't let me delete a partition

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, powershell

I have a USB drive which I can't seem delete a partition on.  I tried Computer Management and GParted on Ubuntu and in desperation I am trying through Admin Powershell/Command Prompt and I can't get it to select the offending partition.

```
    DISKPART> select disk 5

    Disk 5 is now the selected disk.

    DISKPART> list partition

    Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
    -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
    * Partition 1    Primary            115 GB      0 B

    DISKPART> select partition 1

    There is no partition selected.
```

How do I delete partition 1?

Comment: What is your question? "Why?" or "how to delete?" or just "how to select?", or "is it normal?" or "will this partition cause trouble in the future?", or what? Please [edit] the post and be specific.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Altered the wording.  I am trying to delete the partition in question.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Ok.  I changed it again.  Will you help now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the only partition and there's no data you want to save, then you can start from scratch. For GPT use this solution (in Linux): [*How can I quickly clear GPT partition data from a disk?*](https://serverfault.com/a/787210)

> Clear the first block (two 512-byte sectors for MBR and header, and 16KiB for partition entries):
>
> ```
> dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdwhatever bs=512 count=34
> ```
>
> The last part is trickier. […]
>
> ```
> dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdwhatever bs=512 count=34 seek=$((`blockdev --getsz /dev/sdwhatever` - 34))
> ```

For MBR zeroing the first 512 bytes should be enough:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdwhatever bs=512 count=1
```

The GPT solution should work for both, so in case of any doubt just assume GPT. This should get rid of the partition table. I would also `sync` and `partprobe` afterwards.

Comment: Sorry for the long gap.  I just ran through the commands you gave me, the second part of your original code block wouldn't run, it said that -34 was an invalid number and I don't have permission.  However, this seems irrelevant now as after the first and third commands I could use GParted to reparation the drive after creating a new partition table.

Thanks.

Comment: @JamesGilmore There used to be inconsistency in the code (`sdwhatever` vs `sda`) but you probably adjusted this to your case anyway. Maybe you run `blockdev --getsz /dev/sda` as a normal user. If you need `sudo` before `dd`, then the part in backquotes (`\`\``) needs its own `sudo` (like `\`sudo blockdev … \``); this additional `sudo` may ask for a password from background, therefore it's better to run a shell as root and invoke the entire command without `sudo` from it.